# Custom validation not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, customvalidator

I am following the official [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) in order to create a simple custom validation that checks if an email address is formatted properly.

In applications lib folder I have creating file with name **email_format_validator.rb** that contains the following code:

```
class EmailFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not formatted properly")
    end
  end

end
```

and in my model I have the following check:

```
validates :email, presence: true, email_format: true
```

If I comment the **email_format: true** part the views are accessible, otherwise, an error on this row is generated as it is displayed on the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lib` is not automatically added to the `LOAD_PATH`. To fix the issue, either append the `lib` folder in `config.autoload_paths` or add a require at the beginning of the model

```
require 'lib/email_format_validator'
```

Comment: Thanks this fix the issue. But this is strange - I am using torquebox and it automatically add to my LOAD_PATH all jar files in the lib folder. Maybe, it is not adding the .rb files.